# Does the combination of Guardian combinations affect which Guardian you get?

Tags: fantasy-warlord

You can choose to combine 2 of any Guardian as long as they are the same rarity. Does the choice of type of Guardians you pick to combine affect the outcome of which Guardian you receive?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this](http://m.gamevilusa.com/forums/showthread.php?148432-The-Fantasy-Master-Guide!) forum post, the types of guardian you combine DOES make a difference, these are the most beneficial combinations:

God + Gaia

Human + Human

Demon + Demon

Comment: Thanks for the great article. I'll take a look at it in more depth for other things too :)